# stop button doesn't work after a while

Tags: android, button, store, sensors

I am working on a code to collect and store sensor data (accelerometer, gps, ...). so, I have 2 buttons: one to start logging and the second to stop. A couple of seconds after I hit the start button, the stop button does't work and sometimes the screen gets dark (when I go to another app and come back). However, even when the stop button is not working or when I am getting the dark screen, the application seems to be working just fine, I tested the output file that I stored after like 15 minutes and it is clearly stores the data until I swap away the app. does anyone have an idea how I can find what the issue is?

- Note I am writing the data to text files, and I set the sensors at the highest frequency.

I appreciate your time. thanks!

Comment: Are you performing your sensor reading and file writing on a separate Thread or in an AsyncTask?

Comment: No, I should probably use AsyncTask to write data in the background, right?

Comment: Yep! I'm guessing that even though you aren't getting an ANR error your writing operations are what are rendering your button unresponsive.

Comment: OK, thanks for your comments, really appreciate it, I wasn't sure if I should add AsyncTask.

Comment: Generally anything that runs for a while or could block the UI thread should be performed on a separate Thread.